# ajax query not returning json array

Tags: php, ajax, json, function

I have the following php script that is called by jquery ajax

```
    function report_range($time, $ht, $start_date, $end_date) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT type, count(*) FROM tracking WHERE htcode = '$ht' AND type IN ('viewed', 'shared', 'printed', 'emailed', 'used') AND date >= '$start_date' AND date <= '$end_date' GROUP BY type");
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            switch ($result['type']){
                case 'viewed':
                    $viewed = $result['count(*)'];
                    break;
                case 'shared':
                    $shared = $result['count(*)'];
                    break;
                case 'used':
                    $used = $result['count(*)'];
                    break;
                case 'emailed':
                    $emailed = $result['count(*)'];
                    break;
                case 'printed':
                    $printed = $result['count(*)'];
                    break;
            }

        }
        //build the table rows
        return '<tr><td>'.$time.'</td><td>'.$viewed.'</td><td>'.$shared.'</td><td>'.$used.'</td><td>'.$printed.'</td><td>'.$emailed.'</td></tr>'; 
//this is where the problem is, i dont think i am returning the value right.

    }
```

//create the variables to send to json

```
    $stat_1 = report_range('Today', '1672627', date('Y-m-d'), date('Y-m-d'));
    $stat_2 = report_range('Yesterday', $_POST['htcode'], date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday')), date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday')));
    $stat_3 = report_range('Past 30 Days', $_POST['htcode'], date('Y-m-d', strtotime('30 days ago')), date('Y-m-d'));
    $stat_4 = report_range('All Time', $_POST['htcode'], date('Y-m-d', strtotime('3600 days ago')), date('Y-m-d'));
```

//create the json array

```
echo json_encode(array(
        'stat_1'=>$live_1,
        'stat_2'=>$live_2,
        'stat_3'=>$live_3,
        'stat_4'=>$live_4
    ));
```

i can not seem to get a json array with the four variables containing the table rows i am building in the function.

The jquery is working, as it shows the null values.

Comment: can you post your jquery funciton. Also change your $live_x vars to $stat_x vars

Comment: You're not declaring the $live* variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't that $live_1 etc var be $stat_1?

```
echo json_encode(array(
        'stat_1'=>$stat_1,
        'stat_2'=>$stat_2,
        'stat_3'=>$stat_3,
        'stat_4'=>$stat_4
    ));
```

Comment: well crap.. am i embarrassed.. I have been doing this too long today. Thanks for that.... Let that be a lesson to the rest of you. When you reformat your code, check your variables.